# Request for "near" venues keeps failing

Tags: api, foursquare

Request examples:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=Chicago,%20IL&oauth_token=..

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=Chicago&oauth_token=...

This is a proper Foursquare request (with default token) that has worked yesterday but it keeps failing today. Any help, reports, information about it?

Comment: You should not post your OAuth token here. Please revoke the access of the posted token https://foursquare.com/settings/connections. Else anyone can access your Foursquare account.

Comment: thanks for pointing that, but as I said it above...this is default token that you can find it here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=users/self

Comment: No, that is your token. It is linked automatically to your account. To the problem: it seems like the geocoding is broken at the moment. I could not find a single valid geocode. The Foursquare annoucement https://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/browse_frm/month/2012-04 states that geocode data come from http://www.geonames.org/. Their data can translate the geocodes without problem.

Comment: I really thought this is some kind of default token used by everyone. Now I see that foursquare is automatically adding that to my dev API account. thanks. and thanks for your answer. I really hope this will be fixed soon.

Comment: Two things:
(1) Please post the response you get from the "failed" request. It's hard for us to help you debug without knowing how exactly it failed.
(2) The API Explorer uses your OAuth token, so you can get an accurate picture of what the API would return for you. Adding a more clear warning not to post or share it might be helpful -- I'll add a note to do that. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I was getting a "failed_geocode" error for everything, but now it works again. I mean, everything works in my browser now, but now, some request are failing in my app (and everything worked before), and it says: 
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: ___

Comment: well, now I'm getting "failed_geocode" answer again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Developer of the 4sq geocoder here] -- the geocoder appears to be slow today, I'm looking into why right now. Additionally, this should have been returning a 500 to indicate something we were doing wrong. I'm going to both work on geocoder performance/stability and a better error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still experiencing a lot of problems, even today.

Comment: hey peric, did they resolve themselves? I should have mentioned that I found a performance issue on friday of last week and deployed it.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Suppose everything was fine after that - I didn't use that function after that.